# Edit my xml file using php

Tags: php, xml

I want to update dial tag and replace 
`+923455252632` to `+923333578357` here is the code;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Thanks for the call. Configure your number's voice U R L to change this message.</Say>
    <Pause length="1"/>
    <Say voice="alice">Let us know if we can help you in any way during your development. you are a good person </Say>
    <Dial>+923455252632</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: if that's all you want to do, save the xml as a string and use str_replace

Comment: i have to replace whole xml or just a dial section?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an solution, here it is.

`$myfile = fopen("message.xml", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");// opens file in write mode
            @ftruncate($myfile, 0);// trancate previous contant in the xml file named message
            $txt = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                        <Response>
                            <Say voice="alice"> Your call is being transferred to one of our company employees</Say>
                            <Pause length="1"/>
                            <Say voice="alice"> Please wait.</Say>
                            <Pause length="1"/>
                            <Say voice="alice"> Please wait.</Say>
                            <Say voice="alice">Let us know if we can help you. you are a good person </Say>
                            <Dial>'.$employee.'</Dial>
                        </Response>';
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);// Write contant in the file
            fclose($myfile);// Close file`